# How can I italize my Myriad-pro font?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I am trying to make my first illustration. I got text with the Myriad-pro font that I want to make italic. When I click on the button that says Regular next to Myriad-Pro it does not show any other options. I tried a couple of other fonts at random and they also did not have an italic option. From http://www.adobe.com/products/type/creative-suite-6-installed-fonts.html I assume that I should have italic as an option. I don't know if it is relevant but I just activated my license after the 30 day trial.

How can I get the italic font?

Comment: This can be caused by any number of things. There are a bunch of troubleshooting tips to try in this thread on Adobe's forums, check it out: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1147541?tstart=0

Comment: That font list is from Creative Suite 6. If you recently activated a license you will probably have Creative Cloud, not CS6. Quote from the Adobe site: "The Adobe Creative Cloud now provides desktop fonts for its users via Typekit. The same set of fonts previously bundled and installed with Adobe applications is now part of Typekit’s Portfolio plan." In that case you should check your Typekit setup...

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help but maybe taking a screenshot of what you are seeing might help? Sometimes seeing the interface can reveal something that just plain text doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick fix you can use the regular font and use the shear tool to make it look more italic. The shear tool is found with the resize and reshape tool (shortcut: S)

Comment: Hardly a fix with a font like Myriad, which looks completely different in roman and italic.

Comment: It's a fine workaround. Unless the target demo is the graphic design community, no one will know it's not actually italic. Only we typesnobs would know anything is amiss.